# Laravel form using LaravelCollection to redirect to URL with parameter when dropdown selected

Tags: laravel, redirect, routes, laravelcollective

In my blade I have the following dropdown list

```
{!! Form::select('plans', $named_plans, null,['class' => 'form-control'] ) !!}
```

which is populated by a list named `$named_plans` passed by the controller. So far so good.

I need to take the value selected by the user from the dropdown and add it as a parameter to a URL. I can't figure out (and the LaravelCollective documentation is minimal at best) how to append the selected string to a URL (or route) and redirect the user there. Similar to how a dropdown menu works.

For instance, if the user selected `"foo"` from the dropdown, I want to send them to `mylaravelsite/public/displaypage/foo`. I have a route that will process `displaypage/{foo}` just fine if I could just code for the redirect.

Any suggestions would be very helpful.

I'm using Laravel 5.5 with PHP 7 on XAMPP

Comment: Can u use Jquery ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First take the value of selectbox option and add the attribute action to the form

```
$('#selectboxid').change(function(){
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    optionValue = this.value;
    $('#idoftheform').attr('action','public/displaypage/'+optionValue);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Jigs for pointing me in the right direction. The following code worked beautifully for me, added below the `form::select` element. I was able to grab the selected value and append it to the Laravel route (my route "my-plans" directs to 'public/displaypage')

```
<script>
$('[name="plans"]').change(function(){
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
        optionValue = this.value;
    document.location.href="{!!route('my-plans')!!}" + "/" + optionValue;
});
</script>
```

Many thanks.